# Align horizontally 5 text views in Android

Tags: android, textview, radio-button, android-linearlayout

I need your help to solve this problem: 
I have a linear layout with horizontal orientation. Inside this layout I have 5 textviews with visibility:gone. Above this layout I have a radio group with 5 radio button aligned horizontally.

When I check a radio button the corresponding textviews changes his visibility in visible. I want to show a text view below every radio button. Actually they are alle in the same position.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

   <TextView />
   <TextView />
   <TextView />
   <TextView />
   <TextView />
 </LinearLayout>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: show how it looks now, and how you want it to look (show some images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set LinearLayout weigthSum to 1.0. Make each textview weight to 0.2 & visibility to invisible. **View with gone visibility doesn't take any space**.

I made second textview visible. But textview with text "1" will occupy space before textview with text of "2".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.techdesire.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radio_layout">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/value_group">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radio_layout"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="22345678dsada"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="3"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="4"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

On Radio group set onCheckChangeListener then compare id of checked radio button and according to it hide/show textview.See following

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            /*hide all*/
            TextView tv;
            if(checkedID==R.id.radioButton1)
                tv=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            elseif(checkedID==R.id.radioButton2)
                tv=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.text2);
            /* Similarly other else conditions*/
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility:Invisible` instead of `gone`, because with `gone` they don't use any screen so the rest are not really there when the selected one appears, and it will appear at the first position.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
       // set visibility in visible according to Id by using if condition Or  switch
    }
});
```